# Como enviar valor de variável para dentro da class php?

Tags: php, mysql, orientação-a-objetos, pdo, classes

Venho aperfeiçoando as técnicas de uso seguro com conexão em banco de dados e cheguei ao script abaixo.

```
<?php class query_sql {
protected static $conect;
private function __construct() {

    $mysql_host = "";
    $mysql_base = "";
    $mysql_user = "";
    $mysql_pass = "";

    try { self::$conect = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $mysql_host . "; dbname=" . $mysql_base, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
        self::$conect -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        self::$conect -> exec("set names utf8");
        $conect = null; }

    catch(PDOException $error) {
        echo $error -> getMessage(); } }

public static function conect_sql() {
    if (!self::$conect) {
        new query_sql; }
    return self::$conect; } }

$bind_sql = query_sql::conect_sql(); ?>
```

meu próximo passo é aprender como envio os valores de

```
    $mysql_host = "";
    $mysql_base = "";
    $mysql_user = "";
    $mysql_pass = "";
```

junto com os valores abaixo

```
<?php $list_information = $bind_sql -> prepare("SELECT user_email, user_name FROM usuarios WHERE user_email = :user_email LIMIT 1");
$list_information -> bindValue(":user_email", "@");
$list_information -> execute();
$list_information = $list_information -> fetchAll(); ?>
```

só listar acima e comparar abaixo (login como exemplo)

```
<?php $compare_information = $bind_sql -> prepare("SELECT user_email, user_name FROM usuarios WHERE user_email = :user_email AND user_name = :user_name LIMIT 1");
$statement_array = array(":user_email" => "@", ":user_name" => "*");
foreach($statement_array as $array_key => $array_value) {
    $compare_information -> bindValue($array_key, $array_value); }
$compare_information -> execute();
$compare_information = $compare_information -> fetchAll(); ?>
```

Para receber assim

```
<?php foreach($list_information as $list_information) {
echo $list_information["user_email"] . " | " . $list_information["user_name"]; } ?>
```

e assim

```
<?php foreach($compare_information as $compare_information) {
echo $compare_information["user_email"] . " | " . $compare_information["user_name"]; } ?>
```

só preciso de uma ajuda quanto ao o que aprender para que eu envie as variáveis para dentro da class para que elas não precisem estar la dentro, o motivo é que tenho um banco de dados para cada informação, o destino deste script utiliza 4 bancos de dados então eu iria definir qual banco de dados usar em cada prepare (select, delete, att etc.)

Comment: Primeiramente deve entender sobre a visibilidade. Está misturando com métodos estáticos e o construtor está como privado. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa é criar um método auxiliar (privado) que lê um arquivo com os parâmetros da conexão e retorna eles para o construtor.

Digamos que arquivo tenha os valores separados por `;` (isso é apenas um exemplo! não deixe usuário e senha expostos)

```
localhost;loja2015;usuario;senha
```

php:

```
private function getConnectionArgs($file="caminho padrão"){
    return explode(';', file_get_contents($file));
}
```

Seu construtor deve adicionar a chamada do novo método:

```
private function __construct() {
   $args = self::getConnectionArgs();
   self::$conect = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $args[0] . "; dbname=" . $args[1], $args[2], $args[3]);
```

Pode flexibilizar um pouco mais se passar o arquivo na chamda de `conect_sql()` que na primeira vez passará ele para o construtor.

Comment: return exploe(';', file_get_contents($file)); Acredito que esteja faltando a letra 'e' no explode.. Tentei editar, mas não é permitido quando a edição é menor do que 6 caracteres..

Comment: @ThiagoBarros faltou mesmo o `d` xD obrigado, corrigido!

Comment: o método realmente é ótimo, mas queria evitar utilizar arquivos a mais, não teria como no lugar de um arquivo, eu utilizar um array ou uma variável da seguinte forma?

$infor = "server;base;user;pass";
 private function getConnectionArgs($file = $infor) {
     return explode(';', $file); }

eu consegui realizar isso colocando dentro do getConnectionArgs($file = "tudo aqui") mas queria enviar esta variável lá em baixo.

Comment: quanto ao flexibilizar no conect_sql() isso me deixou bem alegre, poderia me dar um exemplo? estou aprendendo bastante.

Comment: teria como eu enviar as informações de login dentro do $bind_sql = query_sql::conect_sql(""aqui""); pois isso seria muito bom, eu iria adicionar um destes em cada função que tenho, que são várias e cada uma delas utiliza dos quatro bancos de dados diferentes, ou seja quero logar o usuário ai seria a função logar e teria um destes com conexão do banco de logins ai depois de autenticado iria no banco de informações com outro destes